# How to Prevent Message Stealing in SpringBoot Integration Tests with RabbitMQ Testcontainer?

Tags: spring-boot, testing, rabbitmq, testcontainers

Imagine the following setup:

- A springBoot Applicaiton with a RabbitListener to a queue
- Two SpringBoot integration tests with RabbitMQ testcontainer

Test A does some arbitrary test cases which require RabbitMQ
Test B has a slightly different test configuration and sends a message from the test code to the application via RabbitMQ and expects something to happen.

Because of the different configuration, Test A will have a different (and cached) spring context than Test B.

When Test A runs, a Rabbit MQ consumer is started. After the test, the Spring context is cached and the rabbit consumer is still running.

When then Test B runs, a second Rabbit MQ consumer is started in the second spring context. When now the test sends a message, sometimes the consumer from context A "steals" the message and thus the test B fails.

I could only "fix" that but running all integration tests with RabbitMQ with `@DirtiesContext` but that make the test suite very very slow.

Is there any other thing that can be done to prevent that? Is there some kind of spring context "pause" that can be called to stop the consumers temporarily until they are resumed when the context is reused?

Comment: You can try to avoid test pollution by isolating the contexts from each other on a logical level, e.g. by having them use different topics.

Comment: Hmm, that would mean making the queue configurable just for testing and change them in the integration test but, yeah that would be an option.